# Get entry url from primary site (using seomatic)

Tags: plugin-seomatic

We're adding a multi-site config to a website.

All sections are being copied over to the new sites from the primary site.

So for example, we now have these two pages:

`mysite.com/services/some-service`

`mysite-ca.com/services/some-serivice`

The `mysite-ca.com` should have a canonical url of `mysite.com/services/some-service`

I'm using seomatic and I'd like to insert the correct dynamic canonical url in the Content Seo Settings.

Is there a way to get an `entry.url` from another site?

Answer (score 1):

So probably you don't want to use canonical URLs there, but rather [hreflang](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) -- and the good news is that as long as all of your localized sites are in the same site group in Craft, SEOmatic does all of this automatically for you:

[SEOmatic Multi-Site Language/Locale Support](https://nystudio107.com/docs/seomatic/Technologies.html#multi-site-language-locale-support)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I'm not sure (I could be wrong) if hreflang is what we want because the countries that are being made are Canada and Australia. They won't be in different languages, but will have duplicate content (a lot of pages), so we want to make sure they all have the canonical root domain + entry specific url